# Ошибка в коде программы с++

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Столкнулся с проблемой в коде, не получается запустить программу.

Выдает ошибку:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 's' is being used without
>   being initialized.

Код

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
void in(int *Massive, int *k)
{
    printf("Введите количество элементов массива:");
    scanf_s("%d", k);
    printf("Ведите элементы массива:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < *k; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &Massive[i]);
    }
}
float se(int *Massive)
{
    int minIndeks;
    int min;
    int *chislo;
    int i;

    int s = minIndeks;
         if (*Massive<min)
    {
            min = *Massive;
            minIndeks = i;//Номер min индекса
            *chislo = min;//min число
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int min = 50;
    int A[min], B[min], C[min];
    int s;
    printf("Индекс min элемента.:%.1f\n", s);
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

В чем причина?

Answer (score 4):

А вы вообще что-то делаете в программе?

```
int s;
printf("Индекс min элемента.:%.1f\n", s);
```

Где **расчет** этого индекса?

От того, что вы где-то объявили какие-то функции, они сами не выполнятся... Да и эти функции тоже, гм...

Ну вот, например:

```
int s = minIndeks;
```

Теперь в `s` просто мусор - присвоили неинициализированную переменную.

```
     if (*Massive<min)
{
        min = *Massive;
        minIndeks = i;//Номер min индекса
        *chislo = min;//min число
}
```

`s` нигде не меняется. Так что тут

```
return s;
```

возвращается? Правильно, опять же мусор...